# Is an Operator to the Zeroeth Power the Identity?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $u:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ be defined such that

$\begin{align*}
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad u(x,y)=(u_1(x,y),u_2(x,y))
\end{align*}$.

Consider the operator

$\begin{align*}
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad A = (-\Delta)^{-1}(u\cdot\nabla) .
\end{align*}$

How do I make sense of $A^0$? Is it simply the identity?

Comment: If you want to keep the *obvious* property $A^{n+m}=A^nA^m$ (meaningful a priory for $n,m\in\mathbb n=\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$) you should  *define* $A^0=id$.

Comment: @Jochen: While that definition is (a) the most reasonable and (b) guarantees that the property holds, you cannot derive $A^0=\operatorname{id}$ from that latter demand. Another definition that would also guarantee that property would be to define $A^0$ as the orthogonal projector to the image of $A$. Which would equal the identity only if $A$ is invertible.

Answer (score 2):

In general if we have an identity element $I$ for an operation $*$ in a set $G$
we can define

$A^0=I$ ( it's more a matter of defition in the end)

With this we can define the composition recursively
$$A^0=I$$
$$A^{n+1}=A^{n}*A $$

With that $A^1=A^0*A=I*A=A$, and so on